# Why is an alpha particle 'specifically' emitted in radioactive element and not other some other particle?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Why is an alpha particle emitted  from any radioactive element if it is decaying? Why can it not emit multiple protons + neutrons one after the other or any other particle that is heavier than an alpha particle?
Is it due to the fact that the atom can become stable faster by emitting multiple alpha particles rather than more number of protons and neutrons individually,
If yes then why can it not emit bigger particle directly to form the stabler element (i.e the product of the decay chain)

Comment: It's stability is higher than other options and there's a compromise with the amount of energy necessary to liberate it from the nucleus?

Comment: *"Why is an alpha particle emitted from any radioactive element if it is decaying?"* That's not true. Some radioactive elements emit beta particles. And of course some elements undergo fission (but they more commonly emit alphas, unless the fission is stimulated by neutrons). There are also other forms of decay, but they are admittedly rare, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decay

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is it due to the fact that the atom can become stable faster by emitting multiple alpha particles

The type of decay is an observational fact, as is the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) and as is the [binding energy curve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve)

[Quantum mechanical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus#Nuclear_models) in conjunction with the binding energy curve,which show alpha particles as very stable, can explain the pattern of decays.  Particularly the alpha particle has high binding energy and acts as a whole particle . It is an interplay between strong forces and electromagnetic forces and mathematics has to be used. See for example [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1422)